# How to pass on a bukkit item-meta Color value as a String?

Tags: java, plugins, methods, minecraft, bukkit

I have stumbled across a problem while trying to make my code dynamic. Instead of making one class (like "cal", as seen below) for each color-code hardcoded (one containing "WHITE", one "RED", etc.) I want to pass on an argument as a String containing the name of the color I want to use in the function.

Code is best explained by code. I am setting a helmet to the players inventory like this:

```
PlayerInventory inven = player.getInventory();
inven.setHelmet(cal());
```

In my code, I am calling this function "cal", to define the material and meta-data of the helmet I am going to set to the player's inventory:

```
public static ItemStack cal(String colorinput)
{
    ItemStack is = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_HELMET);
    LeatherArmorMeta lam = (LeatherArmorMeta)is.getItemMeta();
    lam.setColor(Color.colorinput);
    is.setItemMeta(lam);
    ItemMeta im = is.getItemMeta();
    im.setDisplayName("§f§9Blue Helmet");
    is.setItemMeta(im);
    return is;
}
```

Now, say I did this, then this code works:

```
lam.setColor(Color.WHITE);
```

But if I do this, as I've done in my own code above, then it throws and error at me in the IDE saying 'cannot resolve symbol colorinput':

```
lam.setColor(Color.colorinput);
```

How do I correctly pass on a String to be used next to bukkit.org's "Color", so that I can let users pass on a color-name in a command argument instead of hard-coding all the colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get `Color` values from `String` objects because that class is not an enum.
You must use the provided methods to build them from their red, green and blue components.

Choose between [`Color.fromRGB(int, int, int)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/Color.html#fromRGB(int,%20int,%20int)) and [`Color.fromBGR(int, int, int)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/Color.html#fromBGR(int,%20int,%20int)).
About the first, [you can pick each number here](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm).